# Prices wont show up

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I made a program showing the price for BTC and i was going to make an chrome extension out of it. 
But sadly, i wrote it in PHP. which google extensions does not support.

I looked up a script on Codepen.io to see if it will work at all, 
and i found this one -  https://codepen.io/magnificode/pen/KyMMOB?q=bitcoin+price+&limit=all&type=type-pens

JS file ->

```
  const app = new Vue({
        el: '.btc-badge',
        data: {
            btcUSD: '0.00',
            upDown: 'up',
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getInfo();

            setInterval(()=> {
                this.getInfo();
            }, 1000*60);
        },
        methods: {
            getInfo() {
              axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
                .then(response => {
                  const oldPrice = this.btcUSD
                  const newPrice = parseFloat(response.data.bpi.USD.rate_float).toFixed(2)
                  if (newPrice > oldPrice) {
                      this.upDown = 'up'
                  } else {
                      this.upDown = 'down'
                  }
                  this.btcUSD = newPrice
              });
            }
        },
    });
```

CSS file ->

```
body,html {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ece9e6, #ccc);
        font-smoothing: antialiased;
        align-items: center;
        color: #fafafa;
        display: flex;
        font-family: "macha";
        height: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .card {
        align-items: center;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #141e30, #243b55);
        border-radius: .4em;
        box-shadow: 0 0 66px rgba(#000, 0.3);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 1em;
        position: relative;
        width: 250px;
        height: 300px;
        z-index: 0;

    &:after {
        mix-blend-mode: overlay;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        border-radius: .4em;
        content: '';
        height: calc(100% - 2em);
        left: 0;
        margin: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: calc(100% - 2em);
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

h1 {
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    margin: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

.up {
    color: #42ffa8;
}

.down {
    color: #ff0740;

    &:after {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
}

.up,
.down {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    &:after{
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
        border-color: transparent transparent currentColor transparent;
        content: "";
        height: 0;
        margin-left: .5em;
        margin-top: .1em;
        width: 0;
    }
}

svg {
    bottom: -50%;
    fill: #999;
    left: -20%;
    mix-blend-mode: overlay;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    width: 150%;
    z-index: -1;
}
and the html file ->
```

try{Typekit.load({ async: true });}catch(e){}

```
<div class="btc-badge">
    <div class="card">
        <p>Current Bitcoin price</p>
        <h1>${{ btcUSD }}</h1>
        <p :class="upDown">{{upDown}}</p>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 125"><path d="M50 30L30 40 10 10v80h80V50L70 60"/></svg>
    </div>
</doesnt took the code and put it in a folder, uploaded it and i pressed the little icon for my app. but now i saw that the prices doesn't show up.
```

[image: screenshot - https://gyazo.com/1541b3a6a19de36be6e1240d4cb59155]

Does anyone of you have any idea as to why this is happening? 
Thanks - Jonas.

Comment: Vue is a JavaScript framework, you have to include it via `<script src="https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>` in your code. Also the codepen uses axios for ajax(you have to include it too), check the "JavaScript" tab in "Settings" of the pen.

Comment: okay thanks, but now i'm hit with this - Refused to load the script 'https://vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". same for the axios

Comment: read about csp: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/